# Set relationship between Model classes

Tags: ios, swift, oop

Hello I need to know what would be the standard way to implement this kind a functionality.I'll explain first the whole scenario

I have two Model classes `User` and `Trips`

```
class User: NSObject {


    var email: String?
    var password: String?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?

}

class Trip: NSObject {



    var tripTitle: String?
    var tripSummary: String?

    var departureCountry: String?
    var destinationCountry: String?
}
```

Now in the database I use join query in **trips** and **User** table when I fetch results in Trips Controller because I have to get the user information as well like his `name`

My Program is like this I get each variables from the backend and set them in trip Class object and then pass this object through segue. Now the problem here comes when I have to set the userinformation as well which I get in the same array. I know I have to create user object if I have to set these variables as well but how can I pass two objects through segue or should I have to to do some changing in the trips Model Class? 
Is there any standard or proper way to handle this kind a situation ?

Comment: Declare an object of user inside trip class

Comment: and then how Can I set the variables ? could you please right a little code ? I mean rightnow I am setting like this trip.tripTitle = "hello"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the object of `User` class inside the `Trip` class.

```
class Trip : NSObject
{
    var userInfo           : User? 
    var tripTitle          : String?
    var tripSummary        : String?
    var departureCountry   : String?
    var destinationCountry : String?
}
```

Then you can set the data like:

```
let trip                 = Trip() // Initialise trip
trip.userInfo            = User() // Initialise user
trip.userInfo!.firstName = "Midhun"
trip.userInfo!.lastName  = "MP"
```

Comment: do initilaizing the user is necessary ? this line " trip.userInfo            = User()

Comment: @hellosheikh: It is necessary if and only if you need to set the properties of user object declared inside the trip class. If you don't want to set the user data, then no need to initialise it. Another thing, if you want the userInfo object allocated automatically you can statically allocate it in the Trip class itself.

Comment: sent your request @midhunMP